# Display effect when double left mouse button click

Tags: autohotkey

There is a [script](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8963&p=110140#p110140) that makes the effect when I click mouse buttons.

[Code of this script](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=49774&sid=a19281392f2727e8916d38b1f8671491#p49774).

```
#NoEnv
CoordMode Mouse, Screen
Setup()

~LButton::ShowRipple(LeftClickRippleColor)
~MButton::ShowRipple(MiddleClickRippleColor)
~RButton::ShowRipple(RightClickRippleColor)

Setup()
{
    Global
    RippleWinSize := 170
    RippleStep := 4
    RippleMinSize := 10
    RippleMaxSize := RippleWinSize - 20
    RippleAlphaMax := 0x4147
    RippleAlphaStep := RippleAlphaMax // ((RippleMaxSize - RippleMinSize) / RippleStep)
    RippleVisible := False
    LeftClickRippleColor := 0xff0000
    MiddleClickRippleColor := 0xff00ff
    RightClickRippleColor := 0xffa500

    DllCall("LoadLibrary", Str, "gdiplus.dll")
    VarSetCapacity(buf, 16, 0)
    NumPut(1, buf)
    DllCall("gdiplus\GdiplusStartup", UIntP, pToken, UInt, &buf, UInt, 0)

    Gui Ripple: -Caption +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow +Owner +E0x80000
    Gui Ripple: Show, NA, RippleWin
    hRippleWin := WinExist("RippleWin")
    hRippleDC := DllCall("GetDC", UInt, 0)
    VarSetCapacity(buf, 40, 0)
    NumPut(40, buf, 0)
    NumPut(RippleWinSize, buf, 4)
    NumPut(RippleWinSize, buf, 8)
    NumPut(1, buf, 12, "ushort")
    NumPut(32, buf, 14, "ushort")
    NumPut(0, buf, 16)
    hRippleBmp := DllCall("CreateDIBSection", UInt, hRippleDC, UInt, &buf, UInt, 0, UIntP, ppvBits, UInt, 0, UInt, 0)
    DllCall("ReleaseDC", UInt, 0, UInt, hRippleDC)
    hRippleDC := DllCall("CreateCompatibleDC", UInt, 0)
    DllCall("SelectObject", UInt, hRippleDC, UInt, hRippleBmp)
    DllCall("gdiplus\GdipCreateFromHDC", UInt, hRippleDC, UIntP, pRippleGraphics)
    DllCall("gdiplus\GdipSetSmoothingMode", UInt, pRippleGraphics, Int, 4)

    MouseGetPos _lastX, _lastY
    SetTimer MouseIdleTimer, 5000
    Return

MouseIdleTimer:
    MouseGetPos _x, _y
    if (_x == _lastX and _y == _lastY)
        ShowRipple(MouseIdleRippleColor, _interval:=20)
    else
        _lastX := _x, _lastY := _y
    Return
}

ShowRipple(_color, _interval:=10)
{
    Global
    if (RippleVisible)
        Return
    RippleColor := _color
    RippleDiameter := RippleMinSize
    RippleAlpha := RippleAlphaMax
    RippleVisible := True

    MouseGetPos _pointerX, _pointerY
    SetTimer RippleTimer, % _interval
    Return

RippleTimer:
    DllCall("gdiplus\GdipGraphicsClear", UInt, pRippleGraphics, Int, 0)
    if ((RippleDiameter += RippleStep) < RippleMaxSize) {
        DllCall("gdiplus\GdipCreatePen1", Int, ((RippleAlpha -= RippleAlphaStep) << 24) | RippleColor, float, 3, Int, 2, UIntP, pRipplePen)
        DllCall("gdiplus\GdipDrawEllipse", UInt, pRippleGraphics, UInt, pRipplePen, float, 1, float, 1, float, RippleDiameter - 1, float, RippleDiameter - 1)
        DllCall("gdiplus\GdipDeletePen", UInt, pRipplePen)
    }
    else {
        RippleVisible := False
        SetTimer RippleTimer, Off
    }

    VarSetCapacity(buf, 8)
    NumPut(_pointerX - RippleDiameter // 2, buf, 0)
    NumPut(_pointerY - RippleDiameter // 2, buf, 4)
    DllCall("UpdateLayeredWindow", UInt, hRippleWin, UInt, 0, UInt, &buf, Int64p, (RippleDiameter + 5) | (RippleDiameter + 5) << 32, UInt, hRippleDC, Int64p, 0, UInt, 0, UIntP, 0x1FF0000, UInt, 2)
    Return
}
```

How this script to work:

[image]

I often do double click left mouse button. I want to have the same effect on my gif was and when I double click left mouse button.

Could anyone of you tell what needs to be done to effect other color, when I make double click left mouse button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First variant:

```
~LButton::
    if(A_PriorHotkey = "~LButton" && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 200){
        RippleVisible := False
        ShowRipple(0x2E0854)
    } else {
        ShowRipple(LeftClickRippleColor)
    }
return
```

When I click left mouse button shows the color set for left mouse button, but double-click to change the color to the color for double-click.

[image: Variant 1]

---

---

### Second variant:

```
DoubleClickWait := 200

~LButton::
    SetTimer, SingleClick, Off
    if(A_PriorHotkey = "~LButton" && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < DoubleClickWait){
        ShowRipple(0x2E0854)
    } else {
        SetTimer, SingleClick, -%DoubleClickWait%
    }
return

SingleClick:
    ShowRipple(LeftClickRippleColor)
return
```

Ripple effect are make after DelayTime (200 ms in example). If within 200 ms after the first mouse click will not be second click will show the color for a single click. If 200 ms is committed another click, will show the color for the double-click.

[image: Variant 2]

---

---

Many thanks [**Capn Odin**](https://autohotkey.com/boards/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=67219&sid=fe608f5ebbc888138bebf81c32671115) AutoHotkey user.